# Why does Apache point to /var/www?

Tags: apache, webserver

This is just for my own curiosity. Isn't the purpose of the var directory to hold files that the system writes? For example: logs, cache, lock, etc.

I understand that you can direct apache to point to anywhere by modifying the configuration files, but I just don't understand why the default location would be /var/www.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/var/` is for

> Variable files —- files whose content is expected to continually change during normal operation of the system —- such as logs, spool files, and temporary e-mail files. Sometimes a separate partition.

-- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)

thus not necessarily things that the system writes. I agree that `www` is a bit of an odd duck - it is not supposed to be all that variable. Some distros have it under `/usr/share`, some in other places - `/var/www` is not universally acknowledged. Actually, according to the [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html), the www data should be under `/srv`, but few systems I encountered seem to adhere to that.

Comment: it was back in the days before databases when you had to edit your .html files to post updates.

Answer (score 4):

I was curious too, so I dug through some old mailing list posts. It looks like part of the motivation was that `/var` is most likely kept on a read-write file system or device, whereas other parts of the system might be read-only (CD, etc). As someone else said `/var` is for variable files so by definition it shouldn't be read-only.

Apache don't have control over how an installation is configured by default, that's more down to the linux distribution developers. Looking at some Debian discussions about `/srv/www` the responses seem to be "just leave it as it is".